# Add a Report Menu Item and Disable based on Status

Tags: menu, report, acumatica

I added a report menu item to the Inventory Receipts Reports menu using the Actions sub menu under Screens in the visual editor as shown below.  I want to Disable/Enable this Report Item from the Reports list based on the the Status of the Receipt transaction.  I used to do this via Base.report.********.  ***** being the result I wanted to achieve.  Base.report is no longer valid.  Report is no longer a choice in 2021R1.
How do I achieve this in 2021R1?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the layout editor there is the conditions section, where you can specify the condition in which you want to disable the button.

[image]

This condition would then be available in the disbaled dropdown, and when it is true the button will be automatically disabled